# Simple present or present perfect simple with "WHEN"?

Tags: meaning, differences

From a native speaker's point of view, are these sentences both gramatically acceptable and equally common in spoken/written English?

1. I'll call you when I get to the gym.
2. I'll call you when I've got to the gym.

Comment: For some reason, the second one sounds unnatural to me. To do with the verb _get_, though, not the perfect itself. “I'll call you when I arrive/I've arrived at the gym” is perfectly fine either way. Fairly sure people will use it with _get_ as well, but something about it sounds off to me.

Comment: @Janus: Does the second one sound unnatural because in American English, you would say "*I'll call you when I've **gotten** to the gym*"?

Comment: @Peter Possibly. Though that sounds a bit awkward, too. I think it's just interference from the vastly more common meaning of “I've got to” that makes it a bit garden-pathy.

Comment: I have seen the first one in many cases but I need to know whether or not it can be replaced with the second sentence.

Comment: @Janus: there's no interference in AmE, because *got* and *gotten* distinguish these meanings. The second one sounds perfectly fine in American English if you replace *got* by *gotten* (and it's definitely incorrect with *got*). I don't know about British English.

Comment: I'm with @PeterShor. American English speakers would say either _I get_ or _I've gotten_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the second one is tense. When "have" is the auxiliary (or helping) verb, the second verb takes the past participle which usually ends in "-en" and in this case would be "gotten".

"I'll call you when I've gotten to the gym"

Comment: You should specify that you're talking about American English here; *gotten* is not a word in British English.

Comment: Interesting! Good to know, thanks for the tip. So for you the second sentence is...acceptable?

What about "I've gotten fatter" or some similar sentence?